# How to add a URL parameter by default in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm working on a project where I need to access the windows username from the URL string from the launch of the app. I'm trying to get it to add the "?windowsusername=name" to the URL as soon as the app launches. If I redirect it to another action, it messes my routing up. Is there a way to get this added on launch? I am passing it in from the Startup.cs file and I know it's getting passed in because I can reference it using Razor. However, it's not being added to the URL string. Here's what I've tried in my Startup.cs file:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{windowsUsername}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", windowsUsername = "name" });
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your route to the following one:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
 {
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "default",
         template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
 }
```

Then in the action you can access the username from `id`.

```
public ActionResult YourActionNameGoesHere(string id)
{

}
```

If you hit `ControllerName/YourActionName/name` then the id would has the value of `name`.

Comment: Now that I've done that, I'm getting a 404 error on loading my scripts that are located in my wwwroot/scripts folder. What path do I target to get inside of the wwwroot folder?

Comment: Mvc route have nothing to do with static files.